# foursquare api get list of venues with jquery or c#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, foursquare

**Problem:** I cannot seem to be able to generate tokens or access OAuth 2. I can't seem to find any examples of connecting to OAuth, then using the foursquare api. Has anyone done this before? I've been trying with Jquery but no luck, I'm not very strong with ajax.

Could anyone help me with an example of authenticating, then requesting a list of venues near a location using the api?

I wouldn't mind either Jquery or C# or both if you're super talented and eager to teach.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

The foursquare developer page actually has a pretty detailed walkthrough of how to handle authentication using oauth2:

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/oauth.html

Also, you might find this project helpful, it's a jQuery library for the foursquare API:

https://github.com/praized/marelle

Lastly, for an example of what an api call for nearby venues looks like, you can use the explorer feature of the foursquare developer page. It shows you the json results right there on the page along with the url that generated them:

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore.html#req=venues/search%3Fll%3D40.7,-74

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks but I am well aware of all that you linked me. I was looking for a simple example that shows the process from A to Z. Unfortunately reading a bunch of "snippits" of code that doesn't show the context and piecing together different information is not worth my time. Marelle is hardly developed and the documentation is poor. Either way I appreciate your effort.

Comment: All I did when I learned the OAuth + query process was to go through the oauth walk-through using curl, then queried venues using curl too. If you can do it that way, then the c# version will be a piece of cake